# Extracting last 2 characters of a string using regex and testing for numeric alpha pattern

Tags: regex

I have a string, I want to use a regular expression to find out if the last 2 characters match  NA

i.e., numeric alpha characters

Eg., abcd1e     , efgh4k  for such strings i should get true from the regex pattern compile.

i tried `(\d[a-zA-Z])..$` and it did not work.  It somehow does not identify the last 2 characters

Comment: Did your regex work? If not, why not? Show the entire code and output that produced the error.

Comment: `/\d[a-zA-Z]..$/` actually matches the last __4__ characters, where the last 2 can be _anything_.

Comment: try http://txt2re.com/

Comment: `It somehow does not identify the last 2 characters` - It _DOES_ identify the last 2 characters. What part of the regex do you understand? Can't help you if you don't show an example of what you tried.

Comment: I tried to validate the expression against a string using a online regex editor http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: You selected a correct answer. How does this help you understand what your problem was - a `.` dot metacharacter? You seem to know what everything else is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are matching last two characters for digit and alpha, remove the dots:

```
(\d[a-zA-Z])$
```

Comment: how does this expression find out just the last 2 characters?

Comment: You probably don't need the capturing group.

Comment: @MohammedRafeeq it matches a digit followed by a letter followed by the end of the string, so, last 2 characters (provided they match the pattern.)